# The use of the word 'fellow' instead of the word 'person'

Tags: word-usage, nouns

> *Is he the same fellow who did that?* 
>   
>   vs
>   
>   *Is he the same person who did that?*

In some parts of my country, using the word *fellow* gives a hint of some negativity. At least, it's not a polite way to say the sentence mentioned above. There, others recommend using the word *person*. Is it something that if that person did good thing, we use the second sentence?

Can't we use *fellow* to describe a person here? Is the word *fellow* (other than PHD) always shows suspiciousness as in *"Shh...look at him, he's the fellow who followed my daughter that day."*

WordWeb defines *fellow* as a 'boy' or 'man'.

**Please note:** I'm clear about using the word *fellow,* which means a person who is the member of one's class or profession.

Comment: Fellow is not intrinsically negative but it is a little bit more informal or folksy. *I met a real interesting fellow on the airplane said he worked for John Deere. We talked for the entire trip.*

Comment: I'm curious if the usage of *fellow* varies between American English and British English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In standard English usage, *fellow* is neutral and informal, as Jim notes in his comment. It would be appropriate for relaxed gatherings. Think of a speaker at a technology conference, for instance:

> "And I tell you, this fellow right here, he is an inspiration to all of us."

It would also be appropriate at parties. Think of the song:

> "For he's a jolly good fellow."

On the other hand, it can be used negatively as appropriate. In these contexts it would indicate derision or intensity.

> "Nasty fellow, always coming up with some new scheme for getting his own money with other peoples' effort."
>
> "I won't deny, he works like a horse, but nice? No, he's definitely not a nice fellow."

The use of the word should be a deliberate choice if the context is not completely casual. In a small group of friends having drinks together, it's pretty much always appropriate. A speaker might use it to help loosen up his audience, as in the first sentence I noted. Using it in writing is inadvisable unless the context specfically calls for informality and a folksy feel. A find/replace  from *person* to *fellow* is not a safe or good idea.

Comment: It’s also worth making explicit that “fellow” can only refer to a man, whereas “person” is genderless.